# How to cast to type of object based on the object type?

Tags: c#, reflection, gettype, object-type

I want to avoid using the specific type (forgort how I did it before)

```
var obj = new List<Category>();
obj = (List<Category>)EasyCache.Instance.Item(cacheKey)
```

Something like: obj = (**obj.GetType()???**)EasyCache.Instance.Item(cacheKey)

Comment: you have to make ``Item`` method generic then, how is the implementation of it looks like?

Comment: It is public object Item(string key) - how do I make it generic?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  "casting" doesn't change the underlying type for reference types, it just changes how methods are bound.  Do you want to _convert_ the object?

Comment: @dnrhead 's answer works, and it's exactly what you want (despite it having been downvoted for no reason).

Comment: A fiddle proving @dnrhead 's answer works just fine: https://dotnetfiddle.net/iaJJJB . Again, I'm not sure why it was downvoted. You don't even lose intellisense if doing it that way

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to repeat the type name in the assignment you can just combine the declaration and the assignment:

```
var obj = (List<Category>)EasyCache.Instance.Item(cacheKey)
```

Note that the empty `List<Catgeory>` you create is thrown away since you overwrite it in the next line.  It seems like you create a new one just to allow the use of `var` in the declaration.

`var` and `dynamic` are great tools, but they should not be used to *replace* static type checking.

Answer (score -1):

You could use

```
obj = (dynamic)EasyCache.Instance.Item(cacheKey);
```

It's not a good way, but it should work.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is downvoted... it actually works, and it's a pretty nice method. +1 from me

Comment: I've made a fiddle proving your answer works, which you can add if you feel like it: https://dotnetfiddle.net/iaJJJB

Comment: Hi, why this is not a good way? (only I see it will resolve on runtime...)

Comment: I think he meant that `dynamic` is slow and is generally not the preferred method when there's another "safer" feature hat can do it...

Comment: `dynamic` in this case only bypasses the compiler checking, the casting may be "a bit" slow, but nothing unreasonable: since for the rest of the method you are using the concrete type (not a `dynamic` variable), it won't affect performance on that at all. I don't think there's any *safer* way to do this if you want type-safety... you could use reflection, but that'd be equally slow, and would create all sorts of problems on the code: this is clean, as efficient as a casting to a variable type (not known at compile time) can do, and as safe as any other possible method.

Comment: I downvoted and here's why: 1) `dynamic` should be used when you don't _know_ the type at compile-time (or when you want to support duck-typing).  In this case, the OP knows the type but it just too lazy to repeat it when casting.  2) It defers all type-checking to run-time, where it's harder to detect problems.  If the type is changed in the line above, but nothing downstream is changed to reflect the new type, those bugs are not known until run-time. 3) It's not clear why a cast is necessary - it doesn't change the underlying object so s cast may not be necessary at all.